# Why can't i subscribe again on that same EventEmitter after unsubscribe

Tags: angular, typescript

I subscribe in ngOnInit() of a component (Angular2) and then unsubscribe in ngOnDestroy(). After second initializing of my component it gives me an error:

```
ObjectUnsubscribedError: object unsubscribed
```

In my class i have:

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.chatService.getConversationsEvent()
   .subscribe((data:Data<Array<Conversation>>) => {  
      console.log('from correspondence');
   });
   this.scrollToBottom();
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.chatService.getConversationsEvent().unsubscribe();  
}
```

Comment: Add some code here

Comment: Added code a little

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this code.

```
chatObservable:any;    
ngOnInit() {
       this.chatObservable=this.chatService.getConversationsEvent()
       .subscribe((data:Data<Array<Conversation>>) => {  
          console.log('from correspondence');
       });
       this.scrollToBottom();
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        if(!chatObservable.closed()){
         this.chatObservable.unsubscribe();  
        }
    }
```

Comment: Seems to be working, i'm gonna check it carefuly and if it works i'll rate you. And also in ngOnDestroy you miss this.chatObservable. I'm just new here don't know how to edit it.

Comment: Thank you man, you are the best. The main point is new variable chatObservable and from that variable you have to unsubscribe!!!

Comment: You can also declare chatObservable as `chatObservable: Subscription;`.